# Angular 8 - Can not call webapi

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, angular7, angular8

I am trying to get data from web api using parameter.i can't get data.no t showing error message also.

dash board component

Countrymodel: Country = {
        country_id: '',
        country_name: '',
        status: false
    }
    Countries: Observable;

```
constructor(private api: RestApiService, private router: Router) { }



ngOnInit() {
    let currentUserName = localStorage.getItem('currentUserName');
    console.log(currentUserName);
    this.GetCountry(currentUserName);

}
GetCountry(currentUserName: string) {
    this.Countries = this.api.getcountry(currentUserName);
    console.log(this.Countries);
}
```

}

api.service

```
   export class RestApiService {
Url = 'http://localhost:xxxx/Api/Example/';
header: any;
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    const headerSettings: { [name: string]: string | string[]; } = {};
    this.header = new HttpHeaders(headerSettings);
}
getcountry(currentUserName: string): Observable<Country[]> {
    console.log(this.Url + 'GetCountry?Username=' + currentUserName);
    return this.http.get<Country[]>(this.Url + 'GetCountry?Username=' + currentUserName);
```

}

WebApi

```
[Route("Api/Example/GetCountry")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCountry(string Username)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the call if you want it to execute. See the **[`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request)**

```
this.api.getcountry(currentUserName).subscribe((data)=>{
    console.log(this.Countries);
});
```